# SQLite3 экспорт csv с символом кавычки

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Экспортируя данные в формате csv через DB Browser for SQLite я вручную выставляю разделитель полей и символ кавычки.
Пытаюсь экспортировать те же данные через командную строку. Указать разделитель мне удалось командой `.separator ","` но как указать символ кавычки в мануале найти не могу. По умолчанию поля обрамляются в двойные кавычки `"`, мне же нужно указать, чтобы они экспортировались с одинарными кавычками `'`
Какая команда отвечает за эту настройку?

Comment: Скорее всего нет такой настройки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам подойдет режим не

```
.mode csv
```

а режим:

```
 .mode quote
```

Он делает csv с одинарными кавычками для строковых литералов